# file_get_contents() PHP HTTP request failed error , but successful when proxied through burpsuite proxy

Tags: php, http, file-get-contents

i am using file_get_contents for sending HTTP GET request which result in request failed error but when proxied through burpsuite the request is successful. What could be a reason for this ?

```
$url = 'api';
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => array(
            'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3',
            'Accept: */*'
        ),
        'ignore_errors' => true,
        'proxy' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8080',
        'request_fulluri' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$headers = implode("\n", $http_response_header);

echo "Response headers:\n" . $headers . "\n";

echo "Response body:\n" . $response . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: So, the code in the question is when you use the "burp suite" proxy? What does your code look like when you don't use it? Also, I assume that `$url = 'api';` will, in reality, contain an actual URL? Oh, and where does `$http_response_header` come from?

Comment: _"What could be a reason for this ?"_ - you should probably first of all ask whoever is in charge of that remote(?) endpoint. We can't really know, based on what they might "like" or not like an incoming request ...